# Error: Cannot find module 'semver' Ionic

Tags: nodejs, ionic, npm

```
[ng] ✔ Compiled successfully.
> ionic-lab http://localhost:8100 --host localhost --port 8200 --project-type angular --app-name SieteTrailer --app-version 0.0.1
[lab] internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
[lab]   throw err;
[lab]   ^
[lab] Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
[lab] Require stack:
[lab] - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/lab/bin/ionic-lab
[lab]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
[lab]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
[lab]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
[lab]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
[lab]     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/lab/bin/ionic-lab:8:14)
[lab]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
[lab]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
[lab]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
[lab]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
[lab]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
[lab]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
[lab]   requireStack: [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/lab/bin/ionic-lab' ]
[lab] }

[ERROR] ionic-lab has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).
        
        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

al querer ejecutar ionic con la emulacion visual del celular me marca este error. ya he hecho varios

reinstale nodejs, npm, ionic, limpie los modulos de node, lo ultimo fue `yarn global add npm` pero todo al querer ejecutar el laboratorio este me marca el error, si solo ejecuto `ionic serve` este corre perfectamente

si tendran alguna ayuda o idea les agradeceria bastante

Answer (score 0):

al final logre solucionarlo despues de indagar

```
npm i @ionic/lab@rc
```

este es el comando qu eme funciono